# Change cursor pointer to a custom icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouse-cursor

I would like to change the `cursor` property to imply that the user needs to double click.

Are there any additional icons besides the default one's that can be applied? I saw a list here:

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_cursor)

But I need the `cursor` to look like a `pointer` with two fingers, or some other icon which is better representation for double click.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can basically [use any image you want](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/cursor/).

Use `cursor: url(your-image-path.png), auto;`

```css
div {
   cursor: url(http://65.media.tumblr.com/avatar_91989eab746d_96.png), auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
Winter is coming
</div>
```

Original fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rzusLsvb/)

For IE support you will need to [use .cur format](http://chevronscode.com/index.php/ie-custom-cursor.html)